# wrap in ssl stream with sslStream class

Tags: sockets, ssl, tcp, https, sslstream

when i run this below code, an error occur

```
    string host = "www.google.com";
    int proxyPort = 443;//443;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytes;

    // Connect socket
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(host, proxyPort);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    // Establish Tcp tunnel
    byte[] tunnelRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("CONNECT {0}:443  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\n\r\n", host));
    stream.Write(tunnelRequest, 0, tunnelRequest.Length);
    stream.Flush();

    // Read response to CONNECT request
    // There should be loop that reads multiple packets
    bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

    // Wrap in SSL stream
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(stream);
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);
```

error occur is in this line

```
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);
```

the error is: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

how can i solve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a CONNECT to a HTTPS server, which rightly closes the connection because it's not a valid HTTPS handshake.

A CONNECT is only sent to an upstream proxy (in order to tunnel through the proxy); it's **never** sent to the origin server itself. Even if you were using a proxy, your code to read the response to the CONNECT is buggy and unlikely to work.

Have you considered letting me do the hard work for you? http://fiddler2.com/core/